# Create event for another owner using Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, django, facebook

I'm at the moment working on a web page where the users who visit it should have the possibility to create an event in my web page's name. There is a Page on Facebook for the web page which should be the owner of the user created event. Is this possible? All users are authenticated using Facebook Connect, but since the event won't be created in their name I don't know if that's so much of help. The Python SDK will be used since the event shall be implemented server side.

/ D

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, using the access token provided for your page you can publish to this as you would with a user. If you want to post FROM the USER than you need to use the current user's access token, if you want to post FROM the PAGE then using the access token from the page you can publish to that